# I have a BrowserHelperObject(BHO) in c++ and i need to block some keyboard controls (Ctrl-o) in a i-frame

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts, bho, sidebar

I need to know of a way to prevent the user to 'open a new url' (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) as soon as he has the focus on my sidebar (right-sided iframe).
In fact, my sidebar offers some controls and the user should not be able to 'navigate' to other website through the sidebar.
I'm using a bho in C++ using ATL(active template library), but maybe if anyone knows of a simplier way like in JS(javascript) or PHP(Hypertext Preprocessor) ? All ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What is a BHO? *(From the Acronym Hater)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [IInputObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761804(VS.85).aspx) and pay special attention to [HasFocusIO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761802(v=VS.85).aspx).